# Cannot create access token with Laravel passport?

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-passport

I tried implementing Passport to my project and upon Login attempt, I cannot return the access token.
This is my User model

```php
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
```

And this is the Login controller, the login works, if i try to just return the authenticated user it works, but createToken() method is not recognized for some reason

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function Login(Request $request){
        $login = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|string|max:255',
        ]);
        //Check wether the login credentials are valid
        if( !Auth::attempt($login)){
            return response(['message' => 'Invalid login credentials'], 401);
        }
        else{
            return(Auth::user()->createToken());
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the config file for the auth.php, I added the api driver and provider as the documentation suggested

```php
 'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
     
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this is that you cannot pass any value to the access token. Do the below code :

```
$token = auth()->user()->createToken('API Token')->accessToken;

return response(['user' => auth()->user(), 'token' => $token]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this.

```
public function Login(Request $request){
       $login = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|string|max:255',
        ]);
        //Check wether the login credentials are valid
        if( !Auth::attempt($login)){
            return response(['message' => 'Invalid login credentials'], 401);
        }
        else{
           $token = Auth::user()->createToken('TutsForWeb')->accessToken
            return $token;
        }
    }
```

refer this doc

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#managing-personal-access-tokens